# source not showing on iPhones safari browser

Tags: html, iphone, video, iframe, safari

I am using the below code in order to display a video in my website:

```
<div class="item video-one">
   <video id="f-video" class="slide-video slide-media" autoplay="true" loop="" muted="" preload="metadata">

      <source src="http://myweb.com/name.mp4" type="video/mp4">

   </video>
</div>
```

The code works properly in all devices except iPhones (safari). I have seen that this issue had happened to other people as well but I haven't found a solution.

Do you know if there is a fix or shall I just find another solution to my problem? (maybe hide the video)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was fixed by adding `playsinline` inside the video tag.

```
<video id="f-video" class="slide-video slide-media" autoplay="true" loop muted playsinline preload="metadata">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the recommended settings for WebKit, which iOS uses, and notes on iOS here: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Using their example, the below will play on iPhone (tested on iPhone 7 running iOS 13.3.1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Simple iOS Video Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Video Test</h1>
  <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
      <source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4">
  </video>
</body>

</html>
```

Modifying the above to use your HTML5 and the same view as above also works - tested on the same test device:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Simple iOS Video Test</title>
</head>

<div class="item video-one">
   <video id="f-video" class="slide-video slide-media" autoplay="true" loop="" muted="" preload="metadata">

      <source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">

   </video>
</div>

</html>
```

So your HTML is working. You may find the issue is with your video format - this is a common cause of video not playing from one device to another.